# python: can I have a sparse matrix representation without (explicitly) using integer indices?

Tags: python, indexing, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a dataset that is essentially a sparse binary matrix that represents relationships between elements of two sets. For example, let the 1st set be people (represented by their names), e.g. somehting like this:

```
people = set(['john','jane','mike','joe'])
```

and the 2nd set be a bunch of binary attributes, e.g.

```
attrs = set(['likes_coffee','has_curly_hair','has_dark_hair','drives_car','man_u_fan'])
```

The dataset is represented by a tab-separated data file that assigns some of the attributes to each person, e.g.

```
john    likes_coffee
john    drives_car
john    has_curly_hair
jane    has_curly_hair
jane    man_u_fan
...
```

`attrs` has about `30,000` elements, `people` can be as big `6,000,000`, but the data is sparse, i.e. each person has at most 30-40 attributes

I am looking for a data structure/class in python that would allow me:

- To quickly create a `matrix` object representing the dataset from the corresponding data file
- To be able to quickly extract individual elements of the matrix as well as blocks of its rows and columns. For example, I want to answer questions like

  - "Give me a list of all people with `{'has_curly_hair','likes_coffee','man_u_fan'}`"
  - "Give me a union of attributes of `{'mike','joe'}`"

My current implementation uses a pair of arrays for the two sets and a `scipy` sparse matrix. So if

```
people = ['john','jane','mike','joe']
attrs = ['likes_coffee','has_curly_hair','has_dark_hair','drives_car','man_u_fan']
```

then I would create a sparse matrix `data` of size `4 X 5` and the sample data shown above would correspond to elements

```
data[0,0]
data[0,3]
data[0,1]
data[1,1]
data[1,4]
...
```

I also maintain two inverse indices so that I don't have to invoke `people.index('mike')` or `attrs.index('has_curly_hair')` too often

This works OK but I have to maintain the indices explicitly. This is cumbersome, for instance, when I have two datasets with different sets of people and/or attributes and I need to match rows/columns corresponding to the same person/attribute from the two sparse matrices.

So is there an aternative that would allow me to avoid using integer indices and instead use actual elements of the two sets to extract rows/columns, i.e. something like

```
data['john',:]  # give me all attributes of 'john'
data[:,['has_curly_hair','drives_car']] # give me all people who 'has_curly_hair' or 'drives_car'
```

?

Comment: Have you considered using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)?

Comment: Seems like a job that a simple dict would accomplish just fine, except maybe the matrix creation which would require some logic to extract from the dict. Even so, a dict would be my first try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that no library does exactly what you want, you can create your own class `SparseMatrix` and overload the operator `[]`. Heres is one way to do it (the constructor might be different to what you want to have):

```
class SparseMatrix():
    def __init__(self, x_label, y_label):
        self.data = {}
        for x,y in zip(x_label,y_label):
            print x,y
            self.data[x] = {}
            for attr in y:
                self.data[x][attr] = 1
        return

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x,y = index
        if type(x) is str:
            if type(y) is str:
                return 1 if y in self.data[x] else 0
            if type(y) is slice:
                return self.data[x].keys()
        if type(x) is slice:
            if type(y) is str:
                res = []
                for key in self.data.keys():
                    if y in self.data[key]:
                        res.append(key)
                return res
            if type(y) is list:
                res = []
                for attr in y:
                    res += self.__getitem__((x,attr))
                return res
```

And in the REPL, I get:

```
> data = SparseMatrix(['john','jane','mike','joe'],[['likes_coffee','has_curly_hair'],['has_dark_hair'],['drives_car'],['man_u_fan']])

> data['john',:]
['has_curly_hair', 'likes_coffee']

> data[:,['has_curly_hair','drives_car']]
['john', 'mike']
```

Comment: Thanks. What is `index_list=None` for in `def __getitem__(self, index,index_list=None):`?

Comment: @IZ I didn't need it actually, edited my answer to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the `sparse` formats is actually a dictionary.  A `dok_matrix` is a dictionary subclass, where the keys are of the form `(1,100)`,`(30,334)`.  That is tuples of the i,j indices.

But I found out in other SO questions that access to elements of such a format is actually slower than regular dictionary access.  That is `d[1,100]` is slower than the equivalent `dd[(1,100)]`.  I found that it was fastest to build a regular dictionary, and use `update` to add the values to the sparse `dok`.

But `dok` is useful if you want to transform the matrix to one of the computationally friendly formats like `csr`.  And of course you can access a sparse matrix with `d[100,:]`, something which is impossible with a regular dictionary.

For some uses a default dictionary can be quick and useful.  In other words a dictionary where the keys are 'people', and the values are lists or other dictionaries with 'attribute' keys.

Anyways, sparse matrix does not have provision word indices.  Remember, it's roots are in linear algebra, calculating matrix products and inverses of large sparse numeric matrices.  It's use for text databases is relatively recent.